# How to give React parent component access to children state without form (with Sandbox)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm currently looking for a way to access children `state` from a parent component that will handle API calls for the whole page.

The actual problem is the following:

`Parent` is the parent component that will render two `Child` components.

Each of the `Child` has a state that it is responsible for.

The "Kind of Submit Button" will have a "Kind of Submmit Action" (this is all quoted because this is not a form) and that should fire the function to provide access to the children state. Is there a way (some React feature) to do this without using `<form>` or without creating an intermediate parent component to hold all the state? I want each children to be responsible for its own state.

[Code Sandbox with example of the code below](https://codesandbox.io/s/526rxk2l7l)

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

function ChildOne() {
  const [childOneState, setChildOneState] = useState(false);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h3>Child One</h3>
      <p>My state is: {childOneState.toString()}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setChildOneState(true)}>Change my state</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function ChildTwo() {
  const [childTwoState, setChildTwoState] = useState(false);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h3>Child Two</h3>
      <p>My state is: {childTwoState.toString()}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setChildTwoState(true)}>Change my state</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

function Button(props) {
  return (
    <button onClick={props.kindOfSubmitAction}>Kind of Submit Button</button>
  );
}

function Parent() {
  const childOneState = useRef("i have no idea");
  const childTwoState = useRef("ihave no idea");

  function kindOfSubmitAction() {
    console.log("This is the kindOfSubmit function!");
    // This function would somehow get
    // access to the children state and store them into the refs
    return;
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <h1>Iam Parent</h1>
      <div>
        <b>Child one state is: </b>
        {childOneState.current}
      </div>
      <div>
        <b>Child two state is: </b>
        {childTwoState.current}{" "}
      </div>

      <Button kindOfSubmitAction={kindOfSubmitAction} />

      <ChildOne />
      <ChildTwo />

    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Parent;
```

Comment: The children have to managed their state? Otherwise the solution is to move that state management inside the Parent and let the children be controlled. An "hybrid" solution would be to leave the state managed by the children but keep a "copy" of the value inside the parent. You can provide a callback like `onStateChange` to the children to update the parent `ref` if you absolutely want to avoid the extra render.

Comment: The Child in the real world is an `ImageGallery` that lets the user select some of the images. So it would make sense for it to hold the `state` to know which images have been selected. I'm currently keeping all inside the parent, because it needs access to save the selected images to the database. But I think that this makes my `ImageGallery` less reusable. If it were a `form` I would hold all the `state` on the `form`.

Comment: It means that you can provide a callback to notify the changes from the child to the parent.

Comment: This is possible, but it's really a bad idea and if you go along with the flow (of data, from the top down) you'll really get along much better with React.

Comment: You can use the [State Hoisting](https://reactpatterns.com/#state-hoisting) pattern or the [Render Prop](https://reactpatterns.com/#render-prop) one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When several components need access to the same data, it's time for [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html).